# MySQL Trigger Not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've created simple trigger to create cloud table (MyISAM table just to perfor FULL TEXT searches) however it's not working (the data is not being added).

```
DELIMITER ||

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `table_cloud` ||

CREATE TRIGGER `table_cloud` AFTER INSERT ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `table_cloud` SELECT `id`, `name`, `description` FROM `table` WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
||
DELIMITER ;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NEW.ID` instead of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (`NEW` contains all columns values of the newly inserted row in `'table'`)

Comment: Yes, tried it after creating this question however your answer is correct. Thanks. I'm still newbie in DB game. Cheers!